# How can I batch draw meshes in my Unity scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, batch-drawing

I am using Unity3d to show a dock scene[image: there are thousands of container in my scene]

the containers are updated based on realtime messages. I am optimizing the draw call for this scene. I found that containers are drawing one by one with the draw mesh method. What I do in the code is load a container from prefab and set color

```
instance = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/box1"));
Material material = instance.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
material.color = new Color(r / 255f, g / 255f, b / 255f, 1f);
```

then `gameObject`s are added to the scene one by one. Is there any way to batch  the `gameObject`s and draw them once?

**UPDATE:**
I do some changes for my container prefab to enable the GPU Instancing. Yes, the draw calls are down from 6k to 2k by the dynamic batch. But It cause another problem. All of containers are same color since I use

`gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial.color = ContainerColor`

to set the containers color. Is there any way can solve it ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced. It draws meshes with GPU instancing. But, You can only draw a maximum of 1023 instances at once. So you need to add custom batches.

https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced.html

Comment: Yep, I use Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends of what you need to do with the containers, if they are static, you should look at `StaticBatchingUtility.Combine` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StaticBatchingUtility.Combine.html)

However, if you need them to be dynamic, you should use 1 material for all your meshes, just change the color in the shader will reduce the number of setPass calls.

Comment: there are some containers will be added or removed from the realtime message. all of the container are using one same texture and set the color to the material.color.

Comment: the containers are "static" after they were created. The only changes for them are they will be removed if the realtime message don't contain them.

Answer (score 0):

You used `.material`. That creates a new instance of the material, so don't do that.

Use `.sharedMaterial`. To have different colors, create one material for each color and cache that.